# 'Address Function' example of decision tree complexity is not clear

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-tree

In Arora and Barak's textbook, page 261-262, in decision model complexity, they states:

> Address Function: Suppose that $n = k + 2^k$ and let $f$ be the function that maps $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k, y_1, \dots, y_{2^k}$ to the input $y_x$. That is, the function treats the first $k = \log n$ bits as an index to an array specified by the last $n - k$. Clearly, this function has a decision tree of depth k+1 (examine the first k bits, and use that to find out which bit to examine among the last $n - k$ bits), and hence $D(f) \leq \log n + 1$.

I don't see why $k+1$ is enough here, for example, take $n = 6$ and hence, $k=2$. Then, let's say we have the following strings:

A = $00-1100$

B = $00-1010$

Now, both strings A and B are different but depth 3 is not enough to know the different between these two strings. Is there something missing here?

Comment: The decision tree isn’t supposed to recover the entire input. It is just supposed to compute the function $f$. Moreover, there is a single decision tree which is used for *all* strings. In your case, it reads the first two bits of the input, and then the bit indexed by them, for a total of three bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision tree that Arora and Barak mention gets as input $x,y$ and is only supposed to compute the function $f(x,y) = y_x$. It is not supposed to recover the entire input.

The decision tree proceeds as follows. First, it reads all $k$ bits of $x$. Second, it reads the single bit $y_x$. This is all it needs to compute $f$. In total, it only reads $k + 1$ bits.